# Spring onclick button event should go to java function

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, onclick

I created a project with spring, java, glass fish. Inside I have a .jsp file for my application welcome page. I added a button by calling a Java class that writes the html code.

```
<form:form action='onclick()' method='post'>
<input type='submit' value='Ok' style='width: 150px;'>
</form:from>
```

I would like to call my onclick()-function that I wrote in the source packages in a class Button.java.
How can I do such that when I click on the button I end up in my onclick()?

Comment: HTML page cannot call methods of Java class directly. You need to create a Controller, map it to a specific URL and then set that URL as an action in your form

Answer (score 0):

`Java` class methods can't be called directly from html file. To achieve your requirement in spring, you have to create controllers like below.

**RequestController**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("registration")
public void RequestController{

@GetMapping("/new")
public String new(){
return "register";
}

@PostMapping("/new")
public String new(@ModelAttribute("registration") RegistrationForm registration){
//Do your coding
return "status";
}
}
```

Then invoke in the jsp like below

**register.jsp**

```
<form:form action='/registration/new' modelAttribute="registration" method='post'>
<form:input path="name"/>
<form:input path="designation"/>
<form:input path="email"/>
<input type='submit' value='Ok' style='width: 150px;'>
</form:from>
```

The RegistrationForm is simple POJO class you can create like below

**RegistrationForm**

```
class RegistrationForm{
String name;
String designation;
String email;
}
```